# mysql n to m query

Tags: mysql, relational

I have following table structure

table domains

```
 ID     | name        |
________________________
   1    | example.com |
________________________
   2    | example.net |
________________________
   3    | example.org |
```

table products

```
 ID     | group        |
________________________
   1    | furniture    |
________________________
   2    | electronics  |
________________________
   3    | toys         |
```

table transit

```
 Domain.ID     |Produkt.ID |
_____________________________
   1           |    3      |
_____________________________
   1           |    2      |
_____________________________
   3           |    1      |
```

as variable I have the domain name and in function of this I would like to get all the related products to the domain.

example:domain =>example.com should give me back the properties of product table with ID's 2 and 3

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: thanks this one is a great tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select domains.ID, name,group
from Transit Inner Join Domains ON
Transit.domainId = Domains.Id
INNER JOIN products  ON
Transit.productId = products.Id
Where domains.Name= ?
```